# bar plot xtick frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I want to create a simple bar chart for pandas DataFrame object. However, the xtick on the chart appears to be too granular, whereas if I change the plot to line chart, xtick is optimized for better viewing. I was wondering if I can bring the same line chart xtick frequency to bar chart? Thanks.

```
locks.plot(kind='bar',y='SUM')
```

*EDIT*

Resultant plot:[image]

Comment: Can you show the plots for comparison, or provide data?

Comment: @Pillip-Cloud I can't seem to post image with my reputation under 10. but here's the link [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv337zvv1nupupm/bar.png) .

Comment: Can you link to the "optimal" line plot you're referring to?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can reduce the number of thicks by setting one every `n` ticks, doing something like:

```
n = 10

ax = locks.plot(kind='bar', y='SUM')
ticks = ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()
ticklabels = [l.get_text() for l in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()]
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks[::n])
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(ticklabels[::n])

ax.figure.show()
```