# Time-series plotting inconsistencies in Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Say I have a dataframe `df` where `df.index` consists of `datetime` objects, e.g.

```
> df.index[0]
datetime.date(2014, 5, 5)
```

If I plot it Pandas nicely preserves the `datetime` type in the plot, which allows the user to change the time-series sampling as well formatting options of the plot:

```
  # Plot the dataframe:
  f     = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
  ax    = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
  lines = df.plot(ax=ax)

  # Choose the sampling rate in terms of dates:
  ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),
                                                            interval=1))

  # We can also re-sample the X axis numerically if we want (e.g. every 4 steps):
  N = 4

  ticks      = ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()
  ticklabels = [l.get_text() for l in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()]

  ax.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks[-1::-N][::-1])
  ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(ticklabels[-1::-N][::-1])

  # Choose a date formatter using a date-friendly syntax:
  ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b\n%d'))

  plt.show()
```

However, the above does **not** work for a `boxplot` (the tick labels for the x axis are rendered empty)
:

```
df2.boxplot(column='A', by='created_dt',ax=ax, sym="k.")

# same code as above ...
```

It looks like in the last example, Pandas converts the x-axis labels into **string** type, so the formatter and locators don't work anymore.

This post re-uses solutions from the following threads:

1. Accepted answer to [Pandas timeseries plot setting x-axis major and minor ticks and labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674286/283296)
2. Accepted answer to [Pandas: bar plot xtick frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143857)

Why? How can I use `boxplot` in a way that allows me to use `matplotlib` date locators and formatters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, actually even the line plot is not working correctly, if you have the year show up, you will notice the problem: instead of being 2000 in the following example, the xticks are in 1989.

```
In [49]:
df=pd.DataFrame({'Val': np.random.random(50)})
df.index=pd.date_range('2000-01-02', periods=50)
f     = plt.figure()
ax    = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
lines = df.plot(ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%y%b\n%d'))
print ax.get_xlim()
(10958.0, 11007.0)
```

[image]

```
In [50]:
matplotlib.dates.strpdate2num('%Y-%M-%d')('2000-01-02')
Out[50]:
730121.0006944444
In [51]:
matplotlib.dates.num2date(730121.0006944444)
Out[51]:
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 0, 1, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x051FA9F0>)
```

Turns out datetime data is handled differently in `pandas` and `matplotlib`: in the latter, `2000-1-2` should be `730121.0006944444`, instead of `10958.0` in `pandas`

To get it right we need to avoid using `pandas`'s `plot` method:

```
In [52]:
plt.plot_date(df.index.to_pydatetime(), df.Val, fmt='-')
ax=plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%y%b\n%d'))
```

[image]

Similarly for `barplot`:

```
In [53]:
plt.bar(df.index.to_pydatetime(), df.Val, width=0.4)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%y%b\n%d'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @CT Zhu. Is your understanding that this is a bug in Pandas or perhaps that it provides a basis for a feature request? Or are there arguments to have Pandas work this way?

Comment: @user815423426, this is an old issue, see a related (and old) post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels. I have been struggling with to or not to consider it as a bug, as you see, the problem boils down to the fact that `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex` and `datetime.datetime` are quite different. Personally I think `pandas` `plot` methods are for generating plots when you just want to use as-is. If I want to make customization, I do rather use `matplotlib` straightly. A feature request may be helpful. Cheers!