# Formatting of DateTimeIndex in plot pandas

Tags: date, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, format

I'm having trouble deciphering the documentation for changing tick frequency and date formatting with pandas.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline

mpl.style.use('ggplot')
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8,6)

# grab some price data
px = web.DataReader('AAPL', "yahoo", '2010-12-01')['Adj Close']
px_m = px.asfreq('M', method='ffill')
rets_m = px_m.pct_change()

rets_m.plot(kind='bar')
```

generates this plot:

[image: Generated plot]

Yikes. How can I get the ticks to be every month or quarter or something sensible? And how can the date formatting be changed to get rid of times?

I've tried various things with `ax.set_xticks()` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter` but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas timeseries plot setting x-axis major and minor ticks and labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `plot` method in `pandas`, the `set_major_locator` and `set_major_formatter` methods of `matplotlib` is likely to [fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665990/time-series-plotting-inconsistencies-in-pandas/24690145#24690145).  It might just be easier to  manually adjust the ticks, if you want to stay with ``` pandas``plot ``` methods.

```
#True if it is the first month of a quarter, False otherwise
xtick_idx = np.hstack((True, 
                       np.diff(rets_m.index.quarter)!=0))

#Year-Quarter string for the tick labels.
xtick     = ['{0:d} quarter {1:d}'.format(*item) 
             for item in zip(rets_m.index.year, rets_m.index.quarter)]
ax        =rets_m.plot(kind='bar')

#Only put ticks on the 1st months of each quarter
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(len(xtick))[xtick_idx])

#Adjust the ticklabels
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(np.array(xtick)[xtick_idx])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Derived from this answer, I wrote the [following example](https://gist.github.com/drorata/5165c7ac935a6162714043300852d2b6).

Comment: @Dror You should add this as a proper answer, since it contains additional information.