# Pandas plotting: How to format datetimeindex?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, formatting, datetimeindex

I am doing a barplot out of a dataframe with a 15min datetimeindex over a couple of years.
Using this code:

```
df_Vol.resample(
    'A',how='sum'
).plot.bar(
    title='Sums per year',
    style='ggplot',
    alpha=0.8
)
```

Unfortunately the ticks on the X-axis are now shown with the full timestamp like this: `2009-12-31 00:00:00`.

I would prefer to Keep the code for plotting short, but I couldn't find an easy way to format the timestamp simply to the year (`2009...2016`) for the plot.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207409/formatting-of-datetimeindex-in-plot-pandas?rq=1

Comment: Thanks EdChum, I was hoping there would be a Parameter like ('%Y') to Format this in the df.plot() command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it does not seem to be possible to Format the date within the Pandas df.plot(), I have decided to create a new dataframe and plot from it.

The solution below worked for me:

```
df_Vol_new = df_Vol.resample('A',how='sum')
df_Vol_new.index = df_Vol_new.index.format(formatter=lambda x: x.strftime('%Y')) 
ax2 =df_Vol_new.plot.bar(title='Sums per year',stacked=True, style='ggplot', alpha=0.8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured an alternative (better, at least to me) way is to add the following to `df_Vol_new.plot()` command:

```
plt.legend(df_Vol_new.index.to_period('A'))
```

This way you would reserve `df_Vol_new.index` datetime format while getting better plots at the same time.