Date Format error while plotting graph in python
i have a python code to perform an regression task and i wanted to plot a graph, the problem is im getting a date in 1970s but my dataset has dates in 2023
Date Format: '03-Apr-23'
Plotting snippet
ax1.plot(next_3_months_data['Date '], next_3_months_data['vwap '], label='VWAP', color='g')
ax1.set_title('VWAP vs Date')
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('VWAP')
ax1.grid()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=2))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))

ax2.plot(next_3_months_data['Date '], next_3_months_data['MACD'], label='MACD', color='b')
ax2.plot(next_3_months_data['Date '], next_3_months_data['Signal_Line'], label='Signal Line', color='r')
ax2.set_title('MACD for Next 3 Months')
ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.set_ylabel('MACD')
ax2.grid()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=2))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

i tried changing the date format i couldnt find any remedy.

"%Y" means "year with century", like 2023.  You probably want "%y".

i tried that too but it isnt working

@MohamedAjwada Can you try with %d-%b-%y?

I think this answer to this question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665990/time-series-plotting-inconsistencies-in-pandas

How was ax1 originally created - was it via plt, or by using ax1 = df.plot(...)? Has pandas plotted directly on it using df.plot(..., ax=ax1)? What are the first few values of ax1.get_xticks()? If you're able to share some sample data that may help.
