# Can you stagger minor/major xticklabels in pandas bar plot?

Tags: pandas, plot

Caveat to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143857/pandas-bar-plot-xtick-frequency) is there a way to have pandas plot the minor and major xticklabels to have the days and months and years stacked on top of each other for a bar plot? Kind of like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSOoY.png) but for a bar plot generated by pandas?

----EDIT----

To add onto the scenario..

I have a csv that shows the winners of random challenges throughout a range of time

---record.csv ---

```
date,Team
12/29/2017,BLUE
12/30/2017,GREEN
12/30/2017,GREEN
12/31/2017,GREEN
12/31/2017,BLUE
12/31/2017,BLUE
1/1/2017,GREEN
1/1/2017,BLUE
1/1/2017,GREEN
1/1/2017,BLUE
1/2/2017,GREEN
1/2/2017,BLUE
1/2/2017,GREEN
1/3/2017,GREEN
1/3/2017,BLUE
1/3/2017,BLUE
1/3/2017,GREEN
1/3/2017,GREEN
1/3/2017,GREEN
1/3/2017,BLUE
1/3/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,BLUE
1/4/2017,BLUE
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,BLUE
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,BLUE
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,BLUE
1/5/2017,GREEN
1/5/2017,BLUE
1/5/2017,GREEN
1/5/2017,BLUE
1/5/2017,GREEN
1/6/2017,GREEN
1/6/2017,GREEN
1/6/2017,BLUE
1/6/2017,GREEN
1/6/2017,BLUE
1/6/2017,GREEN
1/6/2017,GREEN
1/6/2017,GREEN


import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

record = pd.read_csv('/desktop/record.csv',header=0,index_col=['date'])
#create a blank dataframe with the entire date range
blank_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=record.date.values.min(),end=record.date.values.max(),freq='D',columns=['date'])

#create df for record grouped by the count of blue and green team for each day
df2 = pd.DataFrame(record.groupby([pd.to_datetime(record['date']), record['Team']]).size())
df2.columns = ['Count']

#combine the blank with the full dataframe
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([blank_df['date'],df2['Team']])
df3 = df2.reindex('date','Team','Count')

# create the pivot table
pivot = df2.pivot(index='date',columns='Team',values='Count').fillna(0)

#create figure time
fig = plt.Figure((3,7),tight_layout=True)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#create the plot
pl = pivot.plot(ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True,grid=False,legend=True,colormap='winter')

plt.show()
```

ok...so this is just a demo i created on the fly...the end point is to put this plot into a QGraphicsScene in PyQt4. I have not been able to actually get the xticklabels to stagger or even set the minor and major xticklabels like the example here:

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(1),
                                                       interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%d\n%a'))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="minor")
ax.xaxis.grid(False, which="major")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('\n\n\n%b%Y'))
```

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels).

I'd really like to figure out how to customize ANY pandas plot xtick and y tick labels that will display nicely in a PyQt GUI. For the time being though, I'd like to figure out how to put this bar plot to have its xticklabels presented like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSOoY.png) line plot. Do you know how?

Comment: Yes there is way. Are you having trouble with your implementation? What have you tried and what issues have you encountered?

Comment: @PaulH I added an edit section to give an example...what I've encountered is that if I try to set the minor and major locator  and formatter, nothing shows for the xticks.

Comment: restart your interpreter and run that code again. getting a lot of errors.

Comment: couple of things, bar plots are really meant for relatively small amounts of data along a categorical axis. in this example, you're trying to plot 365 bars (unless the top few rows of your data are listed as the wrong year as I suspect). In either case, pandas effectively makes a categorical axis with its bar plots. so you'll need to write raw matplotlib to plot this the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compress and correct your example a bit:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas
from matplotlib import pyplot

fakefile = StringIO("""\
date,Team
12/29/2016,BLUE\n12/30/2016,GREEN\n12/30/2016,GREEN
12/31/2016,GREEN\n12/31/2016,BLUE\n12/31/2016,BLUE
1/1/2017,GREEN\n1/1/2017,BLUE\n1/1/2017,GREEN
1/1/2017,BLUE\n1/2/2017,GREEN\n1/2/2017,BLUE
1/2/2017,GREEN\n1/3/2017,GREEN\n1/3/2017,BLUE
1/3/2017,BLUE\n1/3/2017,GREEN\n1/3/2017,GREEN
1/3/2017,GREEN\n1/3/2017,BLUE\n1/3/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,BLUE\n1/4/2017,BLUE\n1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN\n1/4/2017,BLUE\n1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN\n1/4/2017,GREEN\n1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,GREEN\n1/4/2017,GREEN\n1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,BLUE\n1/4/2017,GREEN\n1/4/2017,GREEN
1/4/2017,BLUE\n1/5/2017,GREEN\n1/5/2017,BLUE
1/5/2017,GREEN\n1/5/2017,BLUE\n1/5/2017,GREEN
1/6/2017,GREEN\n1/6/2017,GREEN\n1/6/2017,BLUE
1/6/2017,GREEN\n1/6/2017,BLUE\n1/6/2017,GREEN
1/6/2017,GREEN\n1/6/2017,GREEN
""")

record = pandas.read_csv(fakefile, header=0, parse_dates=[0])
dates = pandas.date_range(start=record.date.min(), end=record.date.max(), freq='D')
full_index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, record['Team'].unique()], names=['date', 'Team'])
df = (
    record.groupby(by=['date', 'Team'])
        .size()
        .reindex(full_index)
        .fillna(0)
        .unstack(level='Team')
)
df.head()
```

So now we have:

```
Team        BLUE  GREEN
date                   
2016-12-29   1.0    0.0
2016-12-30   0.0    2.0
2016-12-31   2.0    1.0
2017-01-01   2.0    2.0
2017-01-02   1.0    2.0
2017-01-03   3.0    5.0
2017-01-04   5.0   11.0
2017-01-05   2.0    3.0
2017-01-06   2.0    6.0
```

My understanding is that pandas does all of its bar plotting with categorical axes. That means that x-values are treated discretely and equally spaced no matter how many there are or how big the quantitative gap is between subsequent values.

But we can easily do an area plot with a proper time series (quantitative) axis:

```
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(7, 3), tight_layout=True)
df.plot.area(ax=ax, stacked=True, grid=False, legend=True, colormap='winter')
```

[image: pandas area plot]

If you really want bars, skip pandas and write the matplotlib code yourself:

```
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(7, 3), tight_layout=True)
ax.bar(left=df.index, height=df['BLUE'])
ax.bar(left=df.index, height=df['GREEN'], bottom=df['BLUE'])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]